# cant get apache to run with php5 in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, apache2, php

I was used to never had a problem with this issue.

I installed like im used to

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5
```

But apache won't execute the php

I tryed and checked various things, and read everything I found, but I cant get it run.

when I try:

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

I get:

```
Module php5 already enabled
```

Also:
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
is setup correct like all the manuals.

Im realy confused.
In general, the 3 commands and everything runs.

Please notice that im using Lubuntu, but I think this could not realy be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found out what was the problem.
It was not any configuration problem with apache or php.

It seems, that the Value `short_open_tag` in default php.ini changed from `On` to `Off`.

All my php sources starts with `<?`

I did not come up with the idea that this could be the problem and I always tried out various configurations about apache.

I could not understand why to change values like this by default.